Irregularity of surfaces for dominant maps
I have a question about an argument in the proof of Lemma 1.2.(1) in Quotients of K3 surfaces modulo involutions by D. Q. Zhang:

Let Let $(X, \sigma)$ be X be a smooth projective K3 surface with an involution $\sigma$ such
that $\sigma^*\omega=-\omega$ for a non-zero holomorphic $2$-form $\omega$. Let $S := X/\sigma$ be the quotient
space and $f : X \to S$ the quotient morphism.


Then (1) $S$ is a smooth surface with irregularity $q(S):= h^1(S, \mathcal{O}_S) = 0$.

The first part on smoothness is fine, see prev. Lemma 1.1.(1). But how do we obtain that the irregularity $q(S)$ is zero?
It is well known that irregularity of K3 surfaces is zero, and we have a dominant finite morphism $f: X \to S$.
Question: Is it always true that $q(S) \le q(X)$? How to see it? If not, what was actually Zhang's argument there to get $q(S)=0$?
Remark: Zhang works in complex setting, ie base field algebraically closed of char $0$. Does it matter for the statement on proposed inequality between irregularities?

Since the K3 surface is simply-connected, every finite unbranched cover of $S$ is intermediate between $S$ and its finite cover $X$.  Thus the fundamental group of $S$ is finite. Therefore the irregularity of $S$ equals zero.

@JasonStarr: Why finiteness of fundametal group of $S$ implies that irregularity of $S$ is zero? (...by the way, the cover in the question was a priori branched; may I assume that in your answer you firstly passed to locus $S' \subset S$ over which $f$ is etale and then exploited that $q(S)$ is a birational invariant; so it's ok to assume $f$ etale, right?)

By the Universa Coefficients Theorem, the first cohomology group is the dual of the first homology group.  If the irregularity is positive, so is the first Betti number.  So the first homology group is infinite.  Therefore the fundamental group is infinite.

You do not need $X$ to be unbranched over $S$.  Every unbranched cover of $S$ pulls back to an unbranched cover of $X$.  Since $X$ is simply connected, there is a section of the pullback unbranched cover.  This equals the graph of an $S$-morphism from $X$ to the original unbranched cover.  In particular the degree of that unbranched cover divides the degree of $X$ over $S$.  So the fundamental group of $S$ is finite.

More generally, for any surjective map $f \colon Y \to X$ of smooth projective varieties, the pullback $H^i(X,\Omega_X^j) \to H^i(Y,\Omega_Y^j)$ is injective for all $i,j$, at least in characteristic $0$. It is true in any characteristic for any Weil cohomology theory (but Hodge and de Rham cohomology have torsion coefficients if $\operatorname{char} k > 0$, and there the result is false); one reference is Kleiman's paper in Dix exposés sur la cohomologie des schémas, Proposition 1.2.4. The proof is a simple consequence of Poincaré duality and the projection formula.

related to this

here another say "low level" argument - but which works only in complex setting: Firstly note that for complex surfaces we have $q(S)= h^0(S, \Omega_S)$; think that's classical Hodge theory + comparison results with sheaf coho. (Note, this fails badly in positive characteristic) Then we are in situation when surjective, (generically) finite maps of smooth schemes $f: X \to Y$ induce injective maps $f^*\Omega_Y \to \Omega_X$ of differerentials. Have still take some time to check it (or find reference) but expect that this should holds always when $K(X)/K(Y)$ separable, esp. in char $0$
